# Mic is not workin in my desktop available: unknown

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones

I am using ubuntu 12.04 Desktop. Mic is not working. I tried same mic in different place,that is working. This is out put of 'pacmd list-sources' Please help me.

root@vijay# pacmd list-sources

```
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.

3 source(s) available.

index: 0
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE 
priority: 1050
volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
        0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 100%
             0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max rewind: 0 KiB
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
monitor_of: 0
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
module: 4
properties:
    device.description = "Monitor of High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
    device.class = "monitor"
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xd6000000 irq 3"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "10de"
    device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
    device.product.name = "High Definition Audio Controller"
    device.string = "1"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
index: 1
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1e.2.analog-stereo.monitor>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: IDLE
suspend cause: 
priority: 1950
volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
        0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 100%
             0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max rewind: 64 KiB
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 371.52 ms; range is 1.00 .. 371.52 ms
monitor_of: 1
card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1e.2>
module: 5
properties:
    device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
    device.class = "monitor"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "Intel ICH7"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Intel ICH7 with AD1888 at irq 22"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_intel8x0"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1e.2"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.2/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.name = "82801G (ICH7 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
index: 2
name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1e.2.analog-stereo>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: SUSPENDED
suspend cause: IDLE 
priority: 9959
volume: 0:  94% 1:  94%
        0: -1.50 dB 1: -1.50 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume:  42%
             -22.50 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max rewind: 0 KiB
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1e.2>
module: 5
properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = "Intel ICH7"
    alsa.id = "Intel ICH"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "0"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "Intel ICH7"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Intel ICH7 with AD1888 at irq 22"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_intel8x0"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1e.2"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.2/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.name = "82801G (ICH7 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "front:0"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "65536"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
    device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
    alsa.mixer_name = "Analog Devices AD1888"
    alsa.components = "AC97a:41445368"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
ports:
    analog-input-microphone;input-microphone-1: Microphone / Microphone 1 (priority 8720, available: unknown)
        properties:

    analog-input-microphone;input-microphone-2: Microphone / Microphone 2 (priority 8719, available: unknown)
        properties:

    analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, available: unknown)
        properties:

    analog-input: Analog Input (priority 8000, available: unknown)
        properties:

    analog-input-video: Video (priority 7000, available: unknown)
        properties:

active port: <analog-input-linein>



 lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller#1  (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller#2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller#3 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller(rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 8400 GS] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5789 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 21)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The source port of your audio card ist set to `<analog-input-linein>` which is the Line-In port, not the microphone port.

To change the input port of an audio card we may issue the following command:

```
pacmd set-source-port <sink-index> <port-name>
```

In you case this would e.g. be

```
pacmd set-source-port 2 'analog-input-microphone;input-microphone-1'
```

We then will also have to make sure that this sink is our default input sink with:

```
pacmd set-default-source 2
```

Depending on your hardware me may have to plug-in a microphone first to make this port available.

**Note** that when running pulseaudio in a per user setting (which is recommended and the default way we do) we do not need to be root to issue the commands above.

Comment: This command is not working
After giving command status is
    active port: <analog-input-microphone;input-microphone-1>

Note:
You given pcmd command. This command is not found,after that i given 
    pacmd set-default-source 2

Comment: ty - edited this typo, sorry. In case you plug in your MIC to port 2 you'll need to adapt the commands, of course.

Comment: still my mic is not working, you any more information.I have checked with different mic also.Please guide me. Thanks you