# Two microphones listed in the input section of Pulseaudio, "Internal microphone" and "Microphone" but the problem is that

Tags: 13.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

Being on a laptop, (Acer Aspire V3-571G to be specific) Ubuntu 13.04, The "Internal Microphone" port selection, all noise played into the microphone is played back to me through the speakers. Being on unity I can't control which ports I use without manually opening the pulse audio volume control, and it's a pain. The 'Microphone" port selection uses the internal and external mic whenever either is plugged in and does not have this issue. I have no more ideas on what to do.

pulseaudio --dump-conf:

```
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-3.0/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = auto
log-level = notice
resample-method = speex-float-1
enable-remixing = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = no
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 10
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 1000000
```

amixer -c 0

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 69 [79%] [-13.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 3 [100%] [36.00dB]
  Front Right: 3 [100%] [36.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Beep',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 24 [77%] [19.50dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 24 [77%] [19.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
```

pacmd list-sources

```
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> 2 source(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 1950
    volume: 0:   0% 1:   0%
            0: -inf dB 1: -inf dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 13 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 80.00 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 4
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb3a10000 irq 45"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.name = "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9959
    volume: 0:  68% 1:  68%
            0: -9.89 dB 1: -9.89 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume:   8%
                 -66.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 80.00 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 4
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC269VB Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC269VB Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb3a10000 irq 45"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.name = "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "14112"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "1764"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analogue Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel PantherPoint HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0269,10250647,00100100 HDA:80862806,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-input-microphone-internal: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-microphone: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-microphone>
```

pacmd dump-volumes

```
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> Sink 0: reference = 0:  60% 1:  60%, real = 0:  60% 1:  60%, soft = 0: 100% 1: 100%, current_hw = 0:  60% 1:  60%, save = yes
    Input 19: volume = 0: 100% 1: 100%, reference_ratio = 0: 100% 1: 100%, real_ratio = 0: 100% 1: 100%, soft = 0: 100% 1: 100%, volume_factor = 0: 100% 1: 100%, volume_factor_sink = 0: 100% 1: 100%, save = no
Source 0: reference = 0:   0% 1:   0%, real = 0:   0% 1:   0%, soft = 0: 100% 1: 100%, current_hw = 0:   0% 1:   0%, save = yes
Source 1: reference = 0:  68% 1:  68%, real = 0:  68% 1:  68%, soft = 0: 102% 1: 102%, current_hw = 0:  67% 1:  67%, save = yes
```

pactl info

```
Server String: unix:/run/user/liam/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 27
Server Protocol Version: 27
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 181
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: liam
Host Name: liam-Aspire-V3-571G
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 3.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Cookie: cccb:95f3
```

Comment: Added the outputs to my question.

Comment: Let me set this straight, you are getting feedback from whatever your speak trough your microphone?

Comment: when set to "internal microphone" port, yes. when set to "microphone" no. but it still uses my internal microphone for "microphone" that's what's spinning me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
`pacmd set-source-port 2 'analog-input-microphone'`
and then:
`pacmd set-default-source 2`
For further details, see this [Mic is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165877/mic-is-not-workin-in-my-desktop-available-unknown) post.